# Testing application on high density, large screen emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

How can I test my app on high density, large screen emulator?

I'm asking about this specifically because it is not listed at "Table-3" in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung released a Galaxy Tab AVD. You can dowload it from your Android AVD manager. It is not a Galaxy S but you will face some of the Samsung's specificities with it. I experienced that a week ago: a bug not reproduceable under HTC or Motorola was reported under Galaxy S - I could reproduce it with the Galaxy Tab.

The AVD system also allows you to change the size of the virtual device and to edit its abstracted density setting, so to emulate a large screen / high density.

By the way, the Galaxy S is a 4 in. / 480x800 (source: [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/fr/galaxys/)). This is not a large screen, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Though its not listed, Galaxy S would surely come under a high density, large screen emulator. That should exactly work as you needed!

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom `AVD Emulator` with whatever density and resolution you need.